# Find upper and lower boundaries in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to get the upper and lower boundaries of a `numeric` value in an array.

```js
const boundaries = [15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90];
const age = 22;
```

For the above example, the outcome should be:

```js
[15, 30]
```

If for example the value is a boundary, it would become the `lower` value in the outcome array. If it is the max boundary or above, it should become the max value.

Example outcomes:

```js
15 => [15, 30]
22 => [15, 30]
30 => [30, 45]
90 => [90]
```

I tried `mapping` through the array and if the `age` is higher => `return boundary`. Then `filter` out the boundaries and calculate the indexes, but this doesn't feel like the correct way to accomplish this.

```js
const boundaries = [15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90];
const age = 22;

// get all lower values
const allLower = boundaries.map((b) => age > b ? b : null).filter(x => x);
const lower = allLower[allLower.length - 1]; // get lowest
const upper = boundaries[boundaries.indexOf(lower) + 1]; // get next

const result = [lower, upper]; // form result

console.log(result);
```

Is there a `shorter` / `better` / `more reliable` way to do this?

Comment: what result do you expect with `age = 30`? what about `15` and `90`?

Comment: @NinaScholz 30 => [30, 45] and 15 = [15], 90 = [90], I will update my question.

Comment: @NinaScholz actually 15 should become [15, 30] also, excuse me

Comment: What's the rule behind the result `[15,30]`? Why not `[15,15]`?

Comment: why for `15` not `30` as well?

Comment: what about `14` and `91`?

Comment: @Sandro everything below the lowest value can be ignored

Comment: @NinaScholz `15` and `30` are treated the same, I updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the previous value and next value and filter the array.

```js
const
    getLowerUpper = (array, pivot) => array
        .filter((v, i, { [i - 1]: prev, [i + 1]: next }) =>
            v <= pivot && next > pivot ||
            prev <= pivot && v >= pivot ||
            prev === undefined && next > pivot ||
            prev < pivot && next === undefined
        ),
    boundaries = [15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90];

console.log(...getLowerUpper(boundaries, 22));  // between
console.log(...getLowerUpper(boundaries, 30));  // direct and next
console.log(...getLowerUpper(boundaries, 10));  // lowest
console.log(...getLowerUpper(boundaries, 15));  // direct and next
console.log(...getLowerUpper(boundaries, 90));  // highest
console.log(...getLowerUpper(boundaries, 100)); // highest
```

Answer (score 5):

Why do you use the indices for this? What if the `boundaries` array is not sorted? Wouldn't it be easier to filter the lists to `allLower` and `allUpper` (containing the values below and above the threshold), and then use `min` and `max` on the resulting arrays?

---

Sample code:

```js
const boundaries = [15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90];
const age = 22;

const allLower = boundaries.filter(x => x < age);
const allUpper = boundaries.filter(x => x > age);

const lowerBound = Math.max(...allLower);
const upperBound = Math.min(...allUpper);
```

Comment: The array is always sorted, and yes could you explain with code?

Comment: should be `allLowerOrEqual` (this code will fail for `15`)

Comment: What do you mean by "fail"? Using the given conditions, `allLower` will only contain values that are below the age

Comment: yes, not fail, it will just be incorrect. E.g. `30` will return `lowerBound = 15 and upperBound = 45`, which is wrong (lowerBound should be 30).

Comment: @axtck don't forget to fix the fault in this answer

Comment: @Sandro I didn't realize this wouldn't work with e.g. `30`

Comment: @Sandro the expected output for the edge cases was added to the question while I was already working on my answer. If the OP decides to change the requirements, the answer should nevertheless help him to get started working on an extended solution

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a good use case for `reduce`:

```js
const boundaries = [15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90];


for (let search of [1, 22, 30, 90, 100]) {

    let [low, upr] = boundaries.reduce(([low, upr], x) =>
        [
            x <= search ? Math.max(low, x) : low,
            x >  search ? Math.min(upr, x) : upr,

        ],
        [-Infinity, +Infinity]
    )

    console.log(low, '<=', search, '<', upr)

}
```

This doesn't require boundaries to be sorted. If they always are, you might consider binary search to locate the lower bound.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a plain for-loop might help you out ;)

```
function getBounds(age) {
  for (let i = 0; i < boundaries.length; i++) {
    if (boundaries[i] <= age && (boundaries[i + 1] ?? Infinity) > age) {
      return boundaries.slice(i, i + 2);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the array, something like this:

```js
const boundaries = [15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90];

const getResult = (array, target) => {
  if (target < array[0] || target > array[array.length - 1]) {
    return [];
  }
  return array.reduce((a, c) => {
    if (c <= target) {
      a[0] = c;
    } else if (c > target && (!a[1] || c < a[a.length - 1])) {
      a[a.length] = c;
    }
    return a;
  }, []);
}

console.log(getResult(boundaries, 22));
console.log(getResult(boundaries, 15));
console.log(getResult(boundaries, 30));
console.log(getResult(boundaries, 90));
console.log(getResult(boundaries, 14));
console.log(getResult(boundaries, 91));
```